# PHP: When trimming, keep empty lines and insert them in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP script which takes the data inserted from a `<textarea>` tag that has been sent by the post method then saves each line into an array.

```
$companies_list = trim($_POST['companies']);
$companies_list = explode ("\n", $companies_list);
$companies_list = array_filter($companies_list, 'trim');
$companies_list_array = array();

foreach ($companies_list as $line) {
   $companies_list_array[] = $line;
}
```

For example it takes the following list

```
CompanyA
CompanyB
CompanyC
CompanyD
```

and saves it to

```
$companies_list_array = array( "CompanyA", "CompanyB", "CompanyC", "CompanyD");
```

This is all great but if there is an empty line, they are not interested in the array as value. How can i do that?

For example if the list of companies is like this:

```
CompanyA

CompanyB
CompanyC

CompanyD
```

I want the script to make it the array like this

```
$companies_list_array = array( "CompanyA", "", "CompanyB", "CompanyC", "", "CompanyD");
```

Comment: So don't call array_filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `array_walk()` instead of `array_filter()`, this is because `array_filter()` will evaluate the return value of the filter function as boolean. On empty lines `trim()` will return an empty string, which will evaluate to boolean false, and the line will get dropped.

Use `array_walk()` like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['companies']);
array_walk($lines, 'trim');

var_dump($lines);
```

Also note that I've dropped unnecessary code.

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "CompanyA"
  [1] =>
  string(0) ""
  [2] =>
  string(8) "CompanyB"
  [3] =>
  string(8) "CompanyC"
  [4] =>
  string(0) ""
  [5] =>
  string(8) "CompanyD"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8dfd31d5c4f72f64406ca9771eda854687a63284):

```
$companies_list = trim($_POST['companies']);
$companies_list = explode ("\n", $companies_list);
$companies_list_array = array();

foreach ($companies_list as $line) {
   $companies_list_array[] = trim($line);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of the statement `if $companies_list_array[] = trim($line);`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$companies_list = preg_split('/\n/', $_POST['companies']);

print_r($companies_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only trim when going over the array like this:

```
$companies_list = explode ("\n", $_POST['companies']);
$companies_list_array = array();
foreach ($companies_list as $line) {
   $companies_list_array[] = trim($line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` will remove empty values. You can try with `array_map` which keep empty values.

```
$companies_list_array = array( "CompanyA      ", "      ", "CompanyB", "CompanyC", "", "CompanyD");

$companies_list_array = array_map('trim', $companies_list_array);
```

Output:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "CompanyA" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(8) "CompanyB" [3]=> string(8) "CompanyC" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(8) "CompanyD" }
```